# I need advice on my Video streaming website

Tags: video, streaming, hosting, video-processing, video-player

I am currently developing a small scale video streaming website. The website will be hosted on our own dedicated server. Our target market is just a small community from all over the world.

My developers and I have already develop the most part of the website. We already have uploading, social media, and our own HTML5 video player. The videos are directly stored and streamed from our dedicated server storage.

My concerns are

1. Should we keep storing the videos in our dedicated server? because I'm now considering using a web services/cloud where we can store the videos but I'm not really sure if this is a good idea because we won't be having like 10K+ videos or more like youtube.
2. What are the advantages of hosting our own videos vs using a video hosting services?
3. Since we are just developing a small scale video streaming site can you please recommend a cheap video hosting site? Where we can customize the player and use our brand and also we should be able to put an ads on it.
4. Currently we have a video player that was develop with HTML5. Is HTML5 a great choice over flash? because we're having a problem with video formats on each browser with HTML5

Thanks.

Comment: For point 1 using a CDN can improve performance as the delivery networks cache the content on servers close to a users location. Since you have users from all over the world some may experience poor connections to your own dedicated server. CDNs cost extra so it's up to you to decide if it's worth it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Storing video could take pretty much disk space, but right now you can choose hosting with big hard disk drive. I would not recommend using 3rd party video storing services.
2. If you host on your own you take control over content. While you grow your project you may need some additional features such as video preview of thumbnails generation - make sure you can do that
3. Keep player on your server anyway. You might only consider storage on a separate server but I would not recommend doing that.
4. HTML5 is great choice especially for future! but Flash is good if you want to make sure it works for most of your website users.

We are specialized in video conferencing, streaming, chat and billing. You may contact me with questions or if you are looking for turnkey solution:
http://www.softservice.org/
http://www.online-webcam.net/

Comment: In regard to your answer to point 1, please explain why it is not recommended. The question mentions clients all over the world. The use of a CDN for geographical coverage can be recommended in this case.

Comment: 1) geo location is not they key, very often a server located closer to client's location would be performing slower than a server located far away. It is more about Internet backbone speed and data-center capabilities
2) we are talking about startup and CDN cost is high. I just did rough calculation of price for popular wowza based cloud streaming compared with dedicated server with 1Gbps connection (cost about $100/month):
* Dedicated server: 60% of 1000Mbps network can transfer 600/8*60*60*24*30/1000 = 194400Gb/month
* Cloud cost: $0.05/Gb * 194400= $9720

$100 vs $9720 makes difference.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I guess I also need to consider my dedicated servers connection speed if I will continue to my servers disk.